# Título de página de ajuda sobre reputação está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

A [página de ajuda sobre reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) está com o título em inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não lembro se sempre esteve assim, ou se o título em inglês foi alterado e isso quebrou a tradução.